# I dont see my devices on the left side-bar in Nautilus

Tags: hard-drive, nautilus, fstab, devices

I have two hard drives `sda` and `sdb` and I also have a cd/dvd drive, but none of those appear on the left side bar of Nautilus.

Using:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- Nautilus 3.14.2

My `etc/fstab` file (I added the last line and that didn't work):

```config
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=90e8e3dc-fdfd-4988-adc2-224b2b915674 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
#/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sdb1    /hdd    ext4    defaults    0    0
UUID=c12a42a2-cb9d-4712-a841-696e25e1fcbb
```

The result of `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="90e8e3dc-fdfd-4988-adc2-224b2b915674" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="105180b1-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="opkumi-Hfh8-bdcL-qJj5-N1mj-t2bj-3jXlrL" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="105180b1-05"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="HD2" UUID="c12a42a2-cb9d-4712-a841-696e25e1fcbb" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ce9ccf02-01"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="cf5ad1ee-5955-4aca-a7c7-f7e33f4e0693" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="502fee58-bca7-46d1-b0e1-09d223c52f9f" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="e07b1b57-3e91-41bf-a222-a7dfb5ba523c" TYPE="swap"
```

I must confess, I have doubts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want sdb1 to appear on the left in nautilus, remove sdb1 from /etc/fstab and reboot.

sda5 should show as "computer" on the left and is mounted at /.

Because sda1 is mounted at /boot it will not show on the left but you can click on computer and then click on boot to view this partition.

Because sdb1 is mounted at /hdd it also will not show on the left but you can access this partition by clicking on computer on the left and then go to hdd.

This is different from the way windows explorer works where each device is listed as C: D: etc. In linux, every thing is a file, sort of.

Comment: hi @mchid.  I did as you suggested and removed sdb1 from /etc/fstab.  After reboot there was no change in nautilus.  i will look at this more, tomorrow, if I have the energy.  i really appreciate the help.

Comment: @williamwallace you do know that it should show up as HD2 right (on the left).

Comment: yes, I did know that.  i gave up.  maybe we can close this as I need to learn some more about file management, in general.  thank you for your help.